# When assessing normality from a QQ-plot, can we use r (lin. cor. coeff.) to do so?

Tags: correlation, normality-assumption, qq-plot

When assessing normality from a QQ-plot, I see online that many sources compare the linearity by plotting a straight line through the two points of intersection of quantiles 1 and 3.

But does it also make sense (and if not, why) to find the linear corelation coeff. of the points within the QQ-plot, and determine linearity from the sample size n combined with the 'critical values of corelation coeff.' table?

Comment: Although some people might have done this, it's scarcely useful.  And those critical values are meaningless because they assume independent responses whereas those on a QQ plot are anything but independent: they are all in order.  Consider reviewing [our threads on interpreting QQ plots](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=qq+interpret+score%3A1) instead.

Comment: Standard tests for normality rely on a statistic that is essentially equivalent to this particular correlation. To get the valid critical value, simulate 1000s of data sets from a normal distribution with the same sample size as in your data, and find this correlation for each simulated data set. The 5th percentile of these 1000s of simulated correlations is your valid critical value. If the correlation coefficient from your original data is less than this critical value, then your data exhibit departures from normality that cannot easily be explained by chance alone and conversely.